# ImportError: cannot import name 'event' from 'sqlalchemy'

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

ImportError: cannot import name 'event' from 'sqlalchemy'
I tried pip install -U sqlalchemy and even uninstall and reinstalling. Dont know whats the problem.
Basically its system file and not my project file.

Below are the versions of each -
Flask-SQLAlchemy    2.4.4   2.4.4
SQLAlchemy  1.3.20  1.3.20

Comment: Perhaps the sqlalchemy package is being masked by another file named "sqlalchemy"?  If you do `print(sqlalchemy)` after importing it, what do you get?

Answer (score 1):

I had a file `sqlalchemy.py` in my application folder (I created the file). It was masking the actual package. Renaming the file solved the problem.